# Getting Client_id, secret and tenantId for authenticating Microsoft Azure via ansible

Tags: azure

I want to run a template on Microsoft Azure using ansible script. For that I have to set the client_id, secret and tenant_id. I am not sure where can I find it on Microsoft Azure?

Answer (score 4):

Well, for that you have to create an Azure AD Application and use that as an Identity. Here's how you do it: https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/resource-group-create-service-principal-portal/
I see no point I
in typing all of the article here.

So the clientID is the ID of an application you can look up on the portal. Secret is what you create (that is visible only when you create it, after that you can't look it up). And the tenantID is the tenantID of your Azure AD

Answer (score -1):

please be sure what client_id orother things you want.

If you asking about get in connection with Azure account then it provides 2 things:
Azure Publish setting file and your subscription id.

So you can check for subscription_id (under settings on Azure portal)
HTH